# Cannot start link in /dev with LD_PRELOAD and ffmpeg

Tags: udev, devices, camera

I successfully start `ffmpeg` on my old webcam with:

```
ssh my_host "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f matroska -" | mplayer - -idle
```

but command:

```
ssh my_host "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/pixart -f matroska -" | mplayer - -idle
```

failed with error:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55fed32516c0] Cannot find a proper format for codec 'none' (id 0), pixel format 'none' (id -1)
Assertion *codec_id != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE failed at src/libavdevice/v4l2.c:815
```

I assume that the environment variable is being passed incorrectly.

`/dev/pixart` is link created by `udev`-rule:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root           6 Sep 27 16:08 pixart -> video0
```